# Force browser to ignore overflowing element from wrapper

Tags: css

I am working on a bit basic webpage layout. Problem is that browser DOESN'T ignore element overflowing from wrapper and add horzinotal scroller if screen is closer than 1050px (1050px is width of wrapper). Check out code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapperMain">
        <div id="headerLeftOverflow"></div>            
        <div id="headerRightOverflow"></div>
        <div id="headerMain"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f9eacc;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Tahoma , sans-serif;
    color: #333333;

}

div#wrapperMain {
   width:  1050px;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
   height: 800px;
}

div#headerMain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 565px;
    background-image: url("../images/header.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#headerLeftOverflow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 271px;
    height: 565px;
    background-image: url("../images/headerLeftOverflow.png");
    top: 0;
    left: -271px;    
}

div#headerRightOverflow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 277px;
    height: 565px;
    background-image: url("../images/headerRightOverflow.png");
    top: 0;
    left: 1050px;   
}
```

**Dont get me wrong.**

I want div with id "headerRightOverflow" visible if screen is enoguht wide. Strange is that div with id "headerLeftOverflow" works properly (if screen is closer than 1050 px, div is hidden).

Comment: If I got you right. U need a div to appear when the width of the screen is wider than 1050px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to quick solution that will make scrollbar disapper - add

```
body{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

BUT, I think you should simply write your code diffrently, without position: absolute.

Comment: Well, OK. Could you give me clue how to rewrite my code to get this thing working?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do with those side divs. When someone have resoultion 1600px - 1050px those elements should be smaller, or should they dissaper or should keep fixed width and be just croped by browser ? :)

Comment: Those elements have image on its background, when somebody have resolution lareger than 1050px, those element provide extra graphics.

Comment: If it's background I should suggest to take background in seperate div and make something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9KUR7/

Answer (score 0):

correct css of wrappermain ti this  way

```
div#wrapperMain { 
overflow:hidden;
   width:  1050px; 
   margin: auto; 
   position: relative; 
   height: 800px; 
}
```

Comment: But this solution hide div with id="headerRightOverflow", I want them visible (if screen is enought wide)

Comment: why are you using position:absolute so much

Comment: I think its the best way how to force browser to not show a scrollers.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is use CSS3 media queries

```
/* Greater than standard 1050px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
//Your Code here that has to be performed when the screen size is more than 1050
}
```

Or you can use Javascript libraries like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

Modernizr  is your starting point for making the best websites and applications that work exactly right no matter what browser or device your visitors use.